# How to implement Accelerometer into app correctly

Tags: android, android-view, accelerometer, android-sensors

I want to control my simple android game (arcanoid) with accelerometer. Paddle in game is now being controlled with touch screen event. I want to control it with accelerometer.

I tried to implement accelerometer into **GameActivity** class which is "controlling" **BreakOutView** class like this:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    // gameView will be the view of the Menu_Layout
    // It will also hold the logic of the Menu_Layout
    // and respond to screen touches as well
    BreakOutView breakoutView;
    private SensorManager sManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;
    Paddle paddle;
  float x;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        breakoutView = new BreakOutView(this);
        sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE); // zisk managera
        if (sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
            accelerometer = sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            sManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }


        // Initialize gameView and set it as the view
        setContentView(breakoutView);


    }


    // This method executes when the player starts the Game
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sManager.registerListener(this,accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        // Tell the gameView resume method to execute
        breakoutView.resume();
    }

    // This method executes when the player quits the Menu_Layout
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sManager.unregisterListener(this);

        // Tell the gameView pause method to execute
        breakoutView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        {



            x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            if (x > 0) {
                breakoutView.paddle.setMovementState(paddle.LEFT);
            }

            else { breakoutView.paddle.setMovementState(paddle.RIGHT);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
}
```

This is code for **BreakOutView** class. 
onTouchEvent method is now disabled because I want to use accelerometer to control Paddle in application.

```
public class BreakOutView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    // This is our thread
    Thread gameThread = null;
    // This is new. We need a SurfaceHolder
    // When we use Paint and Canvas in a thread
    // We will see it in action in the draw method soon.
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;

    // A boolean which we will set and unset
    // when the Menu_Layout is running- or not.
    volatile boolean playing;

    // Game is paused at the start
    boolean paused = true;

    // A Canvas and a Paint object
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;

    // This variable tracks the Menu_Layout frame rate
    long fps;
    Bitmap bitmapBob;
    Bitmap bitmapBall;
    Bitmap bitmapPaddal;
    Bitmap bitmapBrick1;
    Bitmap bitmapBrick2;
    Bitmap bitmapBrick3;


    // The size of the screen in pixels
    int screenX;
    int screenY;
    // The players paddle
    Paddle paddle;
    // A ball
    Ball ball;


    // Up to 200 bricks
    Brick[] bricks = new Brick[24];
    int numBricks = 0;
    // For sound FX
    SoundPool soundPool;
    int beep1ID = -1;
    int beep2ID = -1;
    int beep3ID = -1;
    int loseLifeID = -1;
    int explodeID = -1;
    // The score
    int score = 0;
    int level = 1;
    // Lives
    int lives = 3;
    Rect dest;
    DisplayMetrics dm;
    int densityDpi;

    // When we initialize (call new()) on BreakOutView
    // This special constructor method runs


    public BreakOutView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // The next line of code asks the
        // SurfaceView class to set up our object.
        // How kind.

        // Initialize ourHolder and paint objects
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        paint = new Paint();

        // Get a Display object to access screen details
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();




        // Load the resolution into a Point object
        Point size = new Point();

        //  TODO target API < 13
        display.getSize(size);

        screenX = size.x;
        screenY = size.y;

        // using dpi to set sizes for objects
        dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;
        paddle = new Paddle(screenX, screenY, densityDpi);


        // Create a ball
        ball = new Ball(screenX, screenY);

        // Load the sounds
        // This SoundPool is deprecated but don't worry
        soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

        try {
            // Create objects of the 2 required classes
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;

            // Load our fx in memory ready for use
            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("beep1.wav");
            beep1ID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("beep2.wav");
            beep2ID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("beep3.wav");
            beep3ID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("loseLife.wav");
            loseLifeID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

            descriptor = assetManager.openFd("explode.wav");
            explodeID = soundPool.load(descriptor, 0);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Print an error message to the console
            Log.e("error", "failed to load sound files");
        }


        // Load Images from resource files
        bitmapBob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.wall);
        bitmapBall = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
        bitmapPaddal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
        bitmapBrick1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.brick_red);
        bitmapBrick2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.brick_green);
        bitmapBrick3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.brick_monster);

        //Make Sizes Depending on DPI
        int heightX = densityDpi / 8;
        float length_Paddal = densityDpi / 1.50f;
        int height_Paddal = densityDpi / 7;
        int brickWidth = screenX / 8;
        int brickHeight = screenY / 10;

        bitmapBall = getResizedBitmap(bitmapBall, heightX, heightX);
        bitmapPaddal = getResizedBitmap(bitmapPaddal, length_Paddal, height_Paddal);
        bitmapBrick1 = getResizedBitmap(bitmapBrick1, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        bitmapBrick2 = getResizedBitmap(bitmapBrick2, brickWidth, brickHeight);
        bitmapBrick3 = getResizedBitmap(bitmapBrick3, brickWidth, brickHeight);


        // Create bricks for level 1
        createBricksAndRestart(1);

    }


    public void createBricksAndRestart(int Xlevel) {

        // Put the ball back to the start
        ball.reset(screenX, screenY);

        level = Xlevel;
        switch (Xlevel) {

            case 2:
                // level 2
                ball.xVelocity = 600;
                ball.yVelocity = -1000;

                break;

            // level 3
            case 3:
                ball.xVelocity = 1000;
                ball.yVelocity = -1400;
                break;

            // level 1
            default:
                ball.xVelocity = 400;
                ball.yVelocity = -800;
                break;


        }

        // Brick Size
        int brickWidth = screenX / 8;
        int brickHeight = screenY / 10;

        // Build a wall of bricks
        numBricks = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                bricks[numBricks] = new Brick(row, column, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                numBricks++;
            }
        }

        // if Game is over reset scores ,lives &Level
        if (lives == 0) {
            score = 0;
            lives = 3;
            level = 1;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (playing) {

            // Capture the current time in milliseconds in startFrameTime
            long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // Update the frame
            if (!paused) {
                update();
            }

            // Draw the frame
            draw();

            // Calculate the fps this frame
            // We can then use the result to
            // time animations and more.
            long timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
            if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
                fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
            }

        }

    }

    // Everything that needs to be updated goes in here
    // Movement, collision detection etc.
    public void update() {

        // Move the paddle if required
        paddle.update(fps);
        ball.update(fps);

        // Check for ball colliding with a brick
        for (int i = 0; i < numBricks; i++) {

            if (bricks[i].getVisibility()) {

                if (RectF.intersects(bricks[i].getRect(), ball.getRect())) {
                    bricks[i].setInvisible();
                    ball.reverseYVelocity();
                    score = score + 10;

                    soundPool.play(explodeID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        // Check for ball colliding with paddle
        if (
                ball.getRect().intersect(paddle.getRect()) ||
                        RectF.intersects(paddle.getRect(), ball.getRect()) ||
                        paddle.getRect().intersect(ball.getRect())

                ) {


            ball.reverseYVelocity();

            // ReverseX Direction + IncreaseX speed
            if (paddle.getMovementState() == paddle.RIGHT && ball.xVelocity < 0 || paddle.getMovementState() == paddle.LEFT && ball.xVelocity > 0) {
                ball.reverseXVelocity();
            }

            // SameX Direction + IncreaseX speed
            else if (paddle.getMovementState() == paddle.RIGHT && ball.xVelocity > 0 || paddle.getMovementState() == paddle.LEFT && ball.xVelocity < 0) {
                ball.sameXVelocity();
            }

            /*// Paddle is still, DecreaseX speed
             else if (paddle.getMovementState() == paddle.STOPPED) {
                ball.zeroXVelocity();
            }*/

            // Some intersection Bugs
            ball.clearObstacleY(paddle.getRect().top - 20);

            soundPool.play(beep1ID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        // Bounce the ball back when it hits the bottom of screen
        // And Lose a life
        if (ball.getRect().bottom > screenY) {
            ball.reverseYVelocity();
            ball.clearObstacleY(screenY - 5);

            // Lose a life
            lives--;
            soundPool.play(loseLifeID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);

            if (lives == 0) {
                paused = true;

                //draw Loss;
                canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
                paint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_big));
                canvas.drawText("أنت خسرت!",
                        screenX / 2 - (densityDpi / 1.90f), screenY / 2 + (densityDpi), paint);
                ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

                try {
                    // Wait 3 seconds then reset a new game
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create bricks at level 1
                createBricksAndRestart(1);

            }

        }
        // Pause if cleared screen
        if (score == numBricks * 10) {

            // Create bricks at level 2
            createBricksAndRestart(2);

            // fix for a pause bug
            // so that it won't Pause After finishing the Game
            score = score + 10;
            // Gift the player with 1 new live
            lives = lives + 1;

        } else if (score == (numBricks * 20) + 10) {

            // Create bricks at level 3
            createBricksAndRestart(3);

            // fix for a pause bug
            // so that it won't Pause After finishing the Game
            score = score + 10;
            // Gift the player with 2 new lives
            lives = lives + 2;

        }
        // Pause if cleared screen
        // if score equals to the whole Bricks scores after 3 levels
        else if (score == (numBricks * 10 * 3) + 20) {
            paused = true;
        }


        // Bounce the ball back when it hits the top of screen
        if (ball.getRect().top < 0) {
            ball.reverseYVelocity();
            ball.clearObstacleY(40);

            soundPool.play(beep2ID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        // If the ball hits left wall bounce
        if (ball.getRect().left < 0) {
            ball.reverseXVelocity();
            ball.clearObstacleX(2);

            soundPool.play(beep3ID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        // If the ball hits right wall Velocity
        if (ball.getRect().right > screenX) {
            ball.reverseXVelocity();
            ball.clearObstacleX(screenX - 57);

            soundPool.play(beep3ID, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        }


    }

    // Draw the newly updated scene
    public void draw() {

        // Make sure our drawing surface is valid or we crash
        if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            // Lock the canvas ready to draw
            canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

            // Draw the background color
            // canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.deeppurple));

            dest = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            // Draw bob as background with dest size
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBob, null, dest, paint);

            // Choose the brush color for drawing
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));

            // Draw the ball
            // canvas.drawCircle(ball.getRect().centerX(), ball.getRect().centerY(), 25, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBall, ball.getRect().left, ball.getRect().top, null);

            // Draw the paddle
            //canvas.drawRect(paddle.getRect(), paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapPaddal, paddle.getRect().left, paddle.getRect().top, null);


            // Change the brush color for drawing
            // paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redorange));

            // Draw the bricks if visible
            for (int i = 0; i < numBricks; i++) {
                if (bricks[i].getVisibility()) {
                    // canvas.drawRect(bricks[i].getRect(), paint);

                    switch (level) {
                        case 1:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBrick1, bricks[i].getRect().left, bricks[i].getRect().top, null);

                            break;

                        case 2:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBrick2, bricks[i].getRect().left, bricks[i].getRect().top, null);

                            break;
                        case 3:
                            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapBrick3, bricks[i].getRect().left, bricks[i].getRect().top, null);
                            break;
                    }


                }
            }

            // Choose the brush color for drawing
            paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
            // Draw the score
            paint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));

            // Score Text
            canvas.drawText(
                    "النقاط: " + score
                    , screenX - (densityDpi / 1.50f), screenY / 2, paint);

            // Lives Text
            canvas.drawText("الصحة: " + lives
                    , densityDpi / 5, screenY / 2, paint);

            // Levels Text
            canvas.drawText("المرحلة: " + level
                    , screenX / 2 - (densityDpi / 5), screenY / 2 + (densityDpi / 5), paint);

            // Has the player cleared the screen?
            if (score >= (numBricks * 10 * 3) + 20) {
                paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                paint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_big));
                canvas.drawText("أنت كسبت!", screenX / 2 - (densityDpi / 1.90f), screenY / 2 + (densityDpi / 1), paint);

            }

            // Draw everything to the screen
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

    }

    // If GameActivity is paused/stopped
    // shutdown our thread.
    public void pause() {
        playing = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", "joining thread");
        }

    }

    // If GameActivity is started
    // start our thread.
    public void resume() {
        playing = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    // The SurfaceView class implements onTouchListener
    // So we can override this method and detect screen touches.
 /*   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            // Player has touched the screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                if (!(lives == 0)) {

                    paused = false;
                }

                // If touch motion > Half of the Screen
                if (motionEvent.getX() > screenX / 2) {

                    // move paddle right
                    paddle.setMovementState(paddle.RIGHT);

                } else {

                    // move paddle left
                    paddle.setMovementState(paddle.LEFT);
                }

                break;

            // Player has removed finger from screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                // paddle stopped
                paddle.setMovementState(paddle.STOPPED);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }*/


    // Resize Bitmap function to Handle all the Images from resources the right size
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = newWidth / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        bm.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

}
```

And this is code for **Paddle** class:

```
import android.graphics.RectF;

public class Paddle {

    // Which ways can the paddle move
    public final int STOPPED = 0;
    public final int LEFT = 1;
    public final int RIGHT = 2;
    int scrX;
    // RectF is an object that holds four coordinates - just what we need
    private RectF rect;
    // How long and high our paddle will be
    private float length;
    private float height;
    // X is the far left of the rectangle which forms our paddle
    private float x;
    // Y is the top coordinate
    private float y;
    // This will hold the pixels per second speedthat the paddle will move
    private float paddleSpeed;
    // Is the paddle moving and in which direction
    private int paddleMoving = STOPPED;
    private int MYscreenDPI;

    // This the the constructor method
    // When we create an object from this class we will pass
    // in the screen width and height
    public Paddle(int screenX, int screenY, int screenDPI) {
        // Dynamic size based on each device DPI
        length = screenDPI / 2;
        height = screenDPI / 5;
        MYscreenDPI = screenDPI;
        scrX = screenX;
        // Start paddle in roughly the sceen centre
        x = screenX / 2;
        y = screenY - screenDPI / 4.50f;

        rect = new RectF(x, y, x + length, y + height);

        // How fast is the paddle in pixels per second
        paddleSpeed = 800;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    // This is a getter method to make the rectangle that
    // defines our paddle available in BreakoutView class
    public RectF getRect() {
        return rect;
    }

    public int getMovementState() {
        return paddleMoving;
    }

    // This method will be used to change/set if the paddle is going left, right or nowhere
    public void setMovementState(int state) {
        paddleMoving = state;
    }

    // This update method will be called from update in BreakoutView
    // It determines if the paddle needs to move and changes the coordinates
    // contained in rect if necessary
    public void update(long fps) {
        if (paddleMoving == LEFT) {
            // to fix Paddle going off the Screen
            if (x >= -MYscreenDPI / 10)
                // Decrement position
                x = x - paddleSpeed / fps;
        }

        if (paddleMoving == RIGHT) {
            // to fix Paddle going off the Screen
            if (x <= scrX - length - MYscreenDPI / 14)
                // Increment position
                x = x + paddleSpeed / fps;
        }

        // Apply the New position
        rect.left = x;
        rect.right = x + length;
    }

}
```

When I tried to run it application is always crashing and not working. When I try to use onTouchEvent method to control paddle it is not crashing but accelerometer is not working.

I know that I'm doing something bad. I'm trying to figure it out for like one week but I don't know how to make it working.

If you can tell me any suggestions I will be really thankful. Thank you for all responses.

**--EDIT--**

Here is error message from logcat when I clicked on new game in emulator:

```
2019-04-13 17:30:55.116 7082-7082/com.kazaky.breakout E/SensorManager: Exception dispatching input event. 2019-04-13 17:30:55.122 7082-7082/com.kazaky.breakout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kazaky.breakout, PID: 7082
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at com.kazaky.breakout.GameActivity.onSensorChanged(GameActivity.java:73)
        at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:833)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 2019-04-13 17:31:06.794 7082-7117/com.kazaky.breakout E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19 2019-04-13 17:31:06.794 7082-7117/com.kazaky.breakout E/Surface: queueBuffer (handle=0xe9f16140) failed (No such device)
```

Comment: Include the Stack Trace of your crash.
You can find it in the Logcat Tab in Android Studio.

Comment: @KhaledEmara I added error message from logcat to my post.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the Stack Trace you are trying to access a null object, which in this case I'm guessing `sensroEvent` in `onSensorChanged`.

Add a nullability check and return if `sensorEvent` is `null`, like so:

```
if (sensorEvent == null) return
```

and write the rest of the function after the **Guard Condition**.